# Python code on Raspberry pi

Tags: python

I am, a python novice with little to no knowledge of coding in python, trying to program an application on the Raspberry pi.

Hardware:

- 3 Firgelli Actuators,
- 1 Fan
- 1 Rasp Pi
- 1 16 channel relay
- 3 mechanical switches.

Language:
Python 3 on Rasp Pi OS.

Application: 
The actuators/fan run on a signal from an external mechanical switch for a specific period of time. The application has 3 phases as explained in the ALGO below:

ALGO:

Phase 1.

On hitting switch 1 (each step happens in a succession):

1. Actuator 1 turns on.
2. Fan turns on for a specific period of time.
3. After time up - Fan turns off.
4. After time up - Actuator Turns off.

Phase 2 and 3 have the same function for respective actuators (common fan)

LOGIC:

```
At start:
Check for a switch signal:
 > Once signal received, run respective phase for given time.
   > If another signal received while the phase is running or after run:
     >>Shut down current phase. 
     >>Start the new phase.
```

*Same applies to all three phases.

I could manage to code each phase in a respective python program and it works - separately.

I am now writing a master program which calls the sub-processes(programs) on conditional basis(switch signal).

I would really appreciate if anyone could help me with the structure(Logic) of the master program or how to go about it.

I am currently learning State Machine Architecture in Python... but would like to know if this can be accomplished without using a state-machine and with simple while, if and else loops...

The code is came up with is(only for 2 phases):

```
import time
import os
full_path = os.path.abspath('PHASE1_ON.py')
full_path = os.path.abspath('PHASE2_ON.py')
full_path = os.path.abspath('PHASE1_OFF.py')
full_path = os.path.abspath('PHASE2_OFF.py')
import subprocess
from subprocess import call
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

A = 11 #Relay 1 - System Power
B = 12 #Relay 3 - Actuator OFF
C = 15 #Relay 2 - Actuator ON
D = 16 #Relay 5 - Fan OFF
E = 18 #Realy 4 - Fan ON
X = 22
A = 11 #power
F = 19 #Relay 1 - System Power
G = 23 #Relay 3 - Actuator OFF
H = 21 #Relay 2 - Actuator ON
I = 16 #Relay 5 - Fan OFF
J = 18 #Realy 4 - Fan ON

GPIO.setup(A, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(A, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.setup(B, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(B, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.setup(C,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(C, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.setup(D, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(D, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.setup(E, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(E, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.setup(F, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(F, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.setup(G, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(G, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.setup(H,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(H, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.setup(I, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(I, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.setup(J, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(J, GPIO.HIGH)
input_value1 = GPIO.input(C)
input_value2 = GPIO.input(H)

##=========================================

State = type("State", (object,),{})


class PHASE1ON(State):
    def Execute(self):
        subprocess.call(["python","PHASE1_ON.py"])

class PHASEON(State):
    def Execute(self):
        subprocess.call(["python","PHASE2_ON.py"])

class PHASE1OFF(State):
    def Execute(self):
        subprocess.call(["python","PHASE1_OFF.py"])

class PHASE2OFF(State):
    def Execute(self):
        subprocess.call(["python","PHASE2_OFF.py"])



##============================================

class Transition(object):
    def __init__(self, toState):
        self.toState = toState

    def Execute(self):
        print ("Transitioning...")

##=============================================

class FSM(object):
    def __init__(self,char):
        self.char = char
        self.states = {}
        self.transitions = {}
        self.curState = None
        self.trans = None

    def SetState(self,stateName):
        self.curState = self.states[stateName]

    def Transition(self,transName):
        self.trans = self.transitions[transName]

    def Execute(self):
        if(self.trans):
            self.trans.Execute()
            self.State(self.trans.toState)
            self.trans = None
        self.curState.Execute()

#======================================================

class Char(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.FSM = FSM(self)
        self.PHASE1ON = True
        self.PHASE2ON = True
        self.PHASE1OFF = True
        self.PHASE2OFF = True


##==============================================

if __name__ =="__main__":
    PHASE = Char()

    PHASE.FSM.states["PHASE1ON"] = PHASE1ON()
    PHASE.FSM.states["PHASE2ON"] = PHASE2ON()
    PHASE.FSM.states["PHASE1OFF"] = PHASE1OFF()
    PHASE.FSM.states["PHASE2OFF"] = PHASE2OFF()

    PHASE.FSM.transitions["toPHASE1ON"] = Transition("PHASE1ON")
    PHASE.FSM.transitions["toPHASE2ON"] = Transition("PHASE2ON")
    PHASE.FSM.transitions["toPHASE1OFF"] = Transition("PHASE1OFF")
    PHASE.FSM.transitions["toPHASE2OFF"] = Transition("PHASE2OFF")

    PHASE.FSM.SetState("PHASE1OFF")
    PHASE.FSM.SetState("PHASE2OFF")


    while True:
        input_value1 = GPIO.input(C)
        input_value2 = GPIO.input(H)
        if input_value1 == False:
            print ('The Button1 is pressed... :)')
            while input_value1 == False:
                PHASE.FSM.transitions["toPHASE1ON"]
                PHASE.FSM.transitions["toPHASE2OFF"]
                PHASE.PHASE1ON = False
                PHASE.PHASE2OFF = False
        else:
            PHASE.FSM.transitions["toPHASE1OFF"]
            PHASE.FSM.transitions["toPHASE2OFF"]
            PHASE.PHASE1ON = True
            PHASE.PHASE2OFF = False

        if input_value2 == False:
            print ('The Button2 is pressed... :)')
            while input_value2 == False:
                PHASE.FSM.transitions["toPHASE2ON"]
                PHASE.FSM.transitions["toPHASE1OFF"]
                PHASE.PHASE2ON = False
                PHASE.PHASE1OFF = False
        else:
            PHASE.FSM.transitions["toPHASE1OFF"]
            PHASE.FSM.transitions["toPHASE2OFF"]
            PHASE.PHASE2ON = False
            PHASE.PHASE1OFF = True
        PHASE.FSM.Execute()
```

Just picked up python a week ago. Any input is appreciated. :)

Thanks :)

## ====================================================================

Comment: I think you're confusing architecture and implementation. The behavior you've described *is and always will be* a state machine, regardless of flow-control constructs such as loops. I would suggest reading up on state machines a bit more first.

Comment: We don't write code for you here, but if you post your own code we're happy to help you understand why *specific elements* are not working as expected.

Comment: This question is a bit off topic here, the rules are reasonably strict, but you might get some help at http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hello, Thank You for the feedback. I shall post the code in a moment.

Comment: Hello. I posted the code i came up with. Any input is greatly appreciated ! :)